# não consigo acessar dados de classe já instanciada

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos

Olá, estou desenvolvendo um painel e estou desenolvendo o sistema de instação e na parte de criar a DB, não estou conseguindo acessar váriavel da classe instacidada.

Erro que aparece na tela:

> **Fatal error:** Cannot redeclare class OP_Config

Código:

```
<?php 
include('../config/config.php');

// Inclui o arquivo de conexão com o código descrito anteriormente
include('../sql/class-connection.php');

// Nosso novo banco de dados
$bd = $_POST['db_name'];

$op_config = new OP_Config();
$bd_user = $op_config->datesDb->config['db_user'];

// Cria o banco de dados e da permissão para nosso usuário no mesmo
$db = new DB();
$verifica = $db->getConnection->conn->exec(
    "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `$bd`;
    GRANT ALL ON `$bd`.* TO '$bd_user'@'localhost';
    FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"
);

// Verificamos se a base de dados foi criada com sucesso
if ( $verifica ) {
    echo 'Banco de dados criado com sucesso!';
} else {
    echo 'Falha ao criar banco de dados!';
}
?>
```

Comment: Você pode usar `include_once` ou `require_once`, ou implementar um `autoload`

Answer (score 1):

Utilize o `include_once`, dessa maneira:

```
<?php 
include_once('../config/config.php');

// Inclui o arquivo de conexão com o código descrito anteriormente
include_once('../sql/class-connection.php');

// Nosso novo banco de dados
$bd = $_POST['db_name'];

$op_config = new OP_Config();
$bd_user = $op_config->datesDb->config['db_user'];

// Cria o banco de dados e da permissão para nosso usuário no mesmo
$db = new DB();
$verifica = $db->getConnection->conn->exec(
    "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `$bd`;
    GRANT ALL ON `$bd`.* TO '$bd_user'@'localhost';
    FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"
);

// Verificamos se a base de dados foi criada com sucesso
if ( $verifica ) {
    echo 'Banco de dados criado com sucesso!';
} else {
    echo 'Falha ao criar banco de dados!';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Esse erro `Cannot redeclare class` significa que você está declarando a classe mais de uma vez, verifica se nos seus 2 includes não está definindo a classe `OP_Config` mais de uma vez.

Comment: eu só instanciei ela, no createdb .php e na classse de conexão só que na classe de conexão o nome da variavel do objeto coloquei outro!

Comment: Eu não falo de instanciar e sim declarar a classe mais de uma vez. Copie os códigos dos outros includes na sua pergunta e oculte as informações que possam comprometer a segurança do sistema.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/cbn3PyCH
está, ai os outros dois arquivos!

Comment: Você está fazendo `include('../config/config.php');` duas vezes, uma dentro do `class-connection.php` e outro no seu atual arquivo.

Comment: Remova do seu atual arquivo e tente novamente.

Comment: mas, se eu remover e a instacia que é usada ? vai dar erro!

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda pelo visto aqui vou ter que bolar outra lógica para este sistema porquê desta manéira não vai dar certo!

Comment: @xCoder Você removendo do atual arquivo ainda vai ter o include dentro do `class-connection.php` e tu consegue instanciar sem problemas.

Answer (score 0):

Verifique se você não esta incluindo 2 vezes a mesma classe. Ela pode estar sendo incluida dentro de algum outro **include**.
*Por exemplo:*

> config.php

```
include ('OP_config.php');

class Config 
{
...
}
```

> class-connection.php

```
include('OP_config.php');

class ClassConnection 
{
...
}
```

Pode ser que dentro dos arquivos **.php** esteja invocando a mesma classe duas ou mais vezes.